# Stop useEffect if a condition is met

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` set up how I thought would only run once on initial render but it continues to rerun.

This breaks a function that is supposed to set a piece of state to true if a condition is truthy and show appropriate UI.

This sort of works but then the useEffect runs again flicks back to false immediately. I am also using a use effect to check on first render if the condition is truthy and show appropriate UI if so.

Basically when `setIsPatched` is true I don't want the `useEffect` to rerun because it flicks it back to false and breaks the UI

Here is the function:

```
const [isPatched, setIsPatched] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getApplied(x);
  }, []);

  const getApplied = (x: any) => {
    console.log(x);
    if (x.Log) {
      setIsPatched(true);
      return;
    } else {
      setIsPatched(false);
    }
  };
```

I also pass `getApplied()` to child component which passes a updated data to the function for use in this parent component:

```
const updatePatch = async (id: string) => {
      //check if patch already in db
      const content = await services.data.getContent(id);
      const infoToUpdate = content?.data[0] as CN;

      if (!infoToUpdate.applyLog && infoToUpdate.type == "1") {
        // add applyLog property to indicate it is patched and put in DB
        infoToUpdate.applyLog = [
          { clID: clID ?? "", usID: usID, appliedAt: Date.now() },
        ];

        if (content) {
          await services.data
            .updateX(id, content, usId)
            .then(() => {
              if (mainRef.current) {
                setDisabled(true);
              }
            });
        }
      
        getApplied(infoToUpdate);
      } else {
        console.log("retrying");
        setTimeout(() => updatePatch(id), 1000); // retries after 1 second delay
      }
    };
    updatePatch(id);
  }
```

Comment: if(!isPatched) getApplied(x); inside useEffect.

Comment: sorry can you provide a bit more info?

Comment: Passing an empty array will cause `useEffect` to only run the first time. Either the state updated via a different code path or the whole component is destroyed and recreated.

Comment: The useEffect will just run first time and not rerun until the component is destroyed and recreated again. So your code just will rerender when state change. Help to explain more detail what you want and your code workflow.